# Creating a new matrix in R using old matrix values as exponents

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix mat1

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

it is possible via a very simple command to square all individual values by

```
mat1 * mat1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    9   25
[2,]    4   16   36
```

Now, what I want to do is to create a new matrix where all values are computed by `e^(old_value`), e.g., `e^1`, `e^2`, `e^3` and so forth. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exp` computes the exponential function

```
> mat1 <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
> exp(mat1)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 2.718282 20.08554 148.4132
[2,] 7.389056 54.59815 403.4288
```